Why do we use the labels t2g and eg for complexes in other point groups
The octahedral point group contains the irreducible representations T2g and Eg, which correspond to the triply degenerate and doubly degenerate irreps which are symmetric with respect to a centre of inversion. These irreps give the labels to the molecular orbitals formed in octahedral coordination complexes that transform accordingly: t2g and eg.
My question concerns octahedral coordination complexes which are heteroleptic, and therefore do not possess octahedral symmetry. Why in these cases, where the molecules are actually of an arbitrary point group (such as C4v for example), are molecular orbitals still labeled as t2g and eg in ligand field theory?

Well, the presence of $T2_g$ and $E_g$ and any other irreducible representation label is fixed by the characted table of the point group for the chemical species under study.
If you get an heteroleptic complex, there is no need to panic, the labels involved in the energy diagrams and in any other application of LFT to those complexes will simply be the ones associated to the simmetry labels contained in the character table of the actual point group. I have always seen the correct lables in heteroleptic complexes, it is possible for them to be $t2_g$ or $e_g$, but only if the character table

contains $T2_G$ and $E_g$ irreps.

Well if it is $C_{4v}$ it shouldn't be labelled $e_g$ and $t_{2g}$ for the reasons you give. If you want an example of things being done properly you could look at pages that discuss the Jahn-Teller distortion which in terms of symmetry is doing something very similar.

But what I suspect if happening is one that is very common in Chemistry - the exact, complicated, low symmetry, heteroleptic system is difficult, but the closely related, high symmetry system is very similar and simpler, and we hope that, at least for qualitative discussion, use of the simpler system is enough to describe many of the characteristics of the more complex system. But it is an approximation, and can be misused.
